# GridView items always show in scrollable?

Tags: android, gridview, android-actionbar

I use gridview to show 6 items in two columns and three rows with in the full screen.But it always show in scrollview.For this purpose find total screen height (pixel) then assign (1/3) height in each row.But it always take the entire display height including the status bar & actionbar height.How can i find the screen height without status & action bar. I explored in various blog about it,but not work.I also us support libray v4 & v7 to sho map & action bar.

activity_main.xml

```
<GridView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:columnWidth="150dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/grid"
     android:background="#A1A1A1"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:verticalSpacing="1dp"/>
```

each grid view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#BABABA"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="19sp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public static int height1;
GridView grid;
 String[] web = {"Browse","Important Date","Paper Status","Running Session","Accepted Paper","Map"};
 int[] imageId ={R.drawable.ic_action_search,R.drawable.running_session,R.drawable.paper_status,R.drawable.my_program,R.drawable.reading_list,R.drawable.ic_action_map};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2C5197")));

    // determined the screen pixel
    DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    height1=metrics.heightPixels;

    //determined the screen pixel

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}
}

Here is the adapter class
CustomGrid.java

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private final String[] web;
private final int[] Imageid;
  public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
      mContext = c;
      this.Imageid = Imageid;
      this.web = web;
  }
@Override
public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return web.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  View grid;
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  if (convertView == null) {
    grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_grid_view, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
    textView.setText(web[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);

    //for match with the screen
    grid.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,MainActivity.height1/3));

    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
  return grid;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn"t compute the metrics programatically, but instead let the OS compute by itself if the scrollbar should appear or not, depending on if your grid view is bigger or smaller than the actual screen.
Generally, use ScrollView and nest your GridView inside of it:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Maybe you also should change the layout_height config of your GridView to **wrap_content**, so that it doesn"t fill the whole height:

```
<GridView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Lubos

Comment: I want the gridview items will be placed entire the full screen because of graphical user interface. Thanks to response @Lubos

Comment: If the nesting of the layout to ScrollView is working for you, please accept my answer. Thx!